# How can I alert name of the class Shape,TwoDShape?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I have this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/4Bjjp/) which execution alert and it is work well:

below the code.

```
var Shape = function(){};
var TwoDShape = function(){};
Shape.prototype.name = 'shape';
Shape.prototype.toString = function(){return this.name;};

alert('there is alert');​
```

when I add this line :`extend(TwoDShape, Shape);`

I can't to execution alert as you can see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/4Bjjp/1/)

after this I add lines:

```
var my = new TwoDShape();
alert(my.toString());
alert(TwoDShape.prototype.name);
alert(my.hasOwnProperty('name'));
```

to alert the name of the class `shape` or `TwoDShape` but I can't successfull to display
the class.name why ?

[here is the full code:](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/4Bjjp/5/)
​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do not have function `extend()` inside you code, so the code encounters error there and stopped running.

So I fixed it using jQuery [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), or you can write the `extend()` yourself (see Jimmy's answer).

Secondly, if you want all Shape/TwoDShape instances have the class `name` to be accessible using `toString()`, you need to extend the prototype:

`TwoDShape.prototype = $.extend(TwoDShape.prototype, Shape.prototype);`

See the jsfiddle I created http://jsfiddle.net/4Bjjp/6/ on extending prototype

Answer (score 0):

Your code break because `extend` function does not exist. You've to implement your own to make it work. Here is a simple implementation.

```
function extend(destination, source) {
  for (var key in source) {
    if(source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      destination[key] = source[key];
    }
  }

  return destination;
}
```